# php foreach is slow in looping

Tags: php, loops, foreach

so I'm about to make a table that contains a lot of data in it, and also I need modal to open the data in the pops up. The web has no problem when the data is only like 100 but started to slow when there is 1,9k data in it.

I'm using php foreach to loop the data in the table and modal like this

```
<?php foreach ($wilayah as $wl) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $wl['nmdesa'] ?></td>
        <td><?= $wl['nmsls'] ?></td>
        <td><?= $wl['jenis_sls'] ?></td>
        <td><?= $wl['jkk'] ?></td>
        <td><?= $wl['jkktani'] ?></td>
        <td><?= $wl['status'] ?></td>
        <td><?= $wl['ppljuni'] ?></td>
        <td><?= $wl['nm_petugas'] ?></td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalview<?= $wl['id_wilayah']; ?>">View</button></td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modaledit<?= $wl['id_wilayah']; ?>">Entry</button></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

and I also loop two (view and entry) modal using php foreach. I know its mean the web needs to load 1,9k data per reloading. Its take about 1 minute to load the site in localhost. What should I do?

I try to using another loop method like for but I don't think its will affect the slow problem.

Comment: This isn't PHP being slow, this is the browser being slow when it comes to parsing such massive tables.

Comment: Use pagination. 1.9k rows of data on a single page sounds like UX hell. If you're using Bootstrap consider [Varying modal content](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/modal/#varying-modal-content) so you don't also transfer 3.8k modal HTML codes

Comment: Agreed, i cannot imagine why you think putting that much data on the page at once would lead to a good user experience anyway. Paginate properly, and then this question becomes a non-issue

Comment: `also loop two (view and entry) modal `...not sure why you'd need to make multiple copies of those either. Have one modal and lazy-load data into them on demand using ajax